# sentry/raven with django: how to ignore certain exceptions?

Tags: python, django, exception, sentry

I'd like sentry/raven to ignore all exceptions from a certain function or django module, but looking into the docs and the code, I only saw an option to ignore a custom exception by adding an extra attribute to it. Is there a way to ignore exceptions by function name or module name? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Reading through the source of raven I saw that if you'd like to ignore a certain exceptions you can add them to `IGNORE_EXCEPTIONS` like this:

```
RAVEN_CONFIG = {
    'dsn': '...',
    'IGNORE_EXCEPTIONS': ['exceptions.ZeroDivisionError', 'some.other.module.CustomException'],
    ...
}
```

As for exclusion of certain modules/files the best way would probably be to write your own client and decide whether or not to send a message to sentry. It think you should override the `send` method since it has all the data in more accessible form.

You could do it like this:

```
from raven.contrib.django.client import DjangoClient


class MyClient(DjangoClient):

    def send(self, **kwargs):
        '''
        check if culprit (event name) should be skipped
        '''
        if kwargs.get('culprit', '').startswith('my.module.to.skip'):
            self.logger.info('Skipping entry')
        else:
            return super(MyClient, self).send(**kwargs)
```

and then set your custom client in `settings.py`:

```
SENTRY_CLIENT = 'path.to.module.MyClient'
```

If you want to implement more sophisticated rules for ignoring you should probably check what you can do with the given data (kwargs).